# Method call appears twice

Tags: java, methods, file-handling

I have this code/method:

```
public void Vote() throws IOException{
        File Orig_outFile = new File("C:\\voters.txt");//open the original file     
        File Temp_outFile = new File("C:\\tempvoters.txt");//create temporary file

        BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Orig_outFile));//read the file
        PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter(new PrintWriter(Temp_outFile));//write the data

        vNum=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter voters number: ");
        String line=null;

        while((line=infile.readLine())!=null){

            String something="VOTED";
            String [] info=line.split("/");
            if(info[1].matches(vNum)){

                while(info[0].matches(something)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Voter already voted. Please try again");
                    vNum=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter voters number: ");
                    something="NOT VOTED";
                }
                info[0]="VOTED";
                President();
                Vice_President();
            }
            all=info[0]+"/"+info[1]+"/"+info[2]+"/"+info[3]+"/"+info[4]+"/"+info[5]+"/"+info[6]+"/"+info[7]+"/"+info[8]+"/"+info[9]+"/"+info[10]+"/"+info[11]+"/"+info[12];
            outfile.println(all);
            outfile.flush();
        }

        infile.close();
        outfile.close();

        Orig_outFile.delete();//delete the original file
        Temp_outFile.renameTo(Orig_outFile);//rename the temporary file to original file

    }
```

**EDITED**

For example, I enter `1` in the `vNum` after that the `President()` and `Vice_President()` method appears once and works perfectly fine. After that I tried executing again this method, I enter `2` now in the `vNum`, now the `President()`, and `Vice_President()` *appears twice*. It seems like this method only works in first execution because when I tried executing it again the problem now occurs

Here is the content of my text file (`voting status/voters number/name/age/gender`):

```
NOT VOTED/1/faith/18/Male/...
NOT VOTED/2/george/18/Male...
```

Well here is the code for `President()` method (it is very similar with the `Vice_President()` method):

```
public void President() throws IOException{
        File original = new File("C:\\president_voting_score.txt");//open the original file
        PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(original, true));//write the data

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "WELCOME!\n\n"
                + "Please be guided that you can only vote once.\n"
                + "You cannot repeat the voting process after you click 'OK'.\n"
                + "So please choose carefully.\n"
                + "Click 'OKAY' in this message if you're ready to vote now.\n\n"
                + "THANK YOU AND VOTE WISELY!");
        votepres=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("YOU'LL BE NOW VOTING FOR YOUR PRESIDENT:\n"
                + "Enter 1 for "+pres1+"\n"
                + "Enter 2 for "+pres2+"\n"
                + "Enter 3 for "+pres3+"\n"
                + "Enter 4 for "+pres4));

        while(votepres>4){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input. Please try again");
            votepres=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("YOU'LL BE NOW VOTING FOR YOUR PRESIDENT:\n"
                    + "Enter 1 for "+pres1+"\n"
                    + "Enter 2 for "+pres2+"\n"
                    + "Enter 3 for "+pres3+"\n"
                    + "Enter 4 for "+pres4));
        }

        if (votepres==1){
            int[] incrementVote={1};
            for (int v : incrementVote){
                result1 = (pvotes[v - 1]+=1);
                }
            outfile.println("1="+pres1+"="+result1);
            }
        else if (votepres==2){
            int[] incrementVote={2};
            for (int v : incrementVote){
                result2 = (pvotes[v - 1]+=1);
                }
            outfile.println("2="+pres2+"="+result2);
            }
        else if (votepres==3){
            int[] incrementVote={3};
            for (int v : incrementVote){
                result3 = (pvotes[v - 1]+=1);
                }
            outfile.println("3="+pres3+"="+result3);
            }
        else if (votepres==4){
            int[] incrementVote={4};
            for (int v : incrementVote){
                result4 = (pvotes[v - 1]+=1);
                }
            outfile.println("4="+pres4+"="+result4);
            }
            outfile.close();

    }
```

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the execution. Your loop iterates based on what's in your file, so how could you expect us to know without showing us the contents of the file? Even if you showed us, you are asking for debugging help, which is off-topic.

Comment: You should also provide the relevant input for first and second try. From the code I#d guess that you initially would have a "VOTED" line that by your code is being duplicated. You should hover then experience your two methods to be called one time extra per call of your method.

Comment: @VinceEmigh i am not really familiar in using a debugger. the only thing i know about it is if there is an error will appear in the console, which in this code, nothing will appear.

Comment: So you should focus on learning how to use a debugger. It's one of the most useful tools you'll come across as a developer. IDEs come with them built-in.

Comment: @rpy can you suggest on how to do it?

Comment: @VinceEmigh yes i will have to learn more about the debugger because i am not really familiar with it as of now. but i don't really have time anymore because i need to submit this program today and this is the only problem that appears in my whole program.

Comment: Please add the initial content of your input file (for the OK case and the failure case). Then read about debugging with your dev env!! And.. please note that "VOTED" also matches a value of "NOT VOTED"

Comment: I'm sorry, but if we bent the rules for you (even this one time), everyone else would want the rules bent for them aswell. You shouldn't have put it off for so long. It would take quite some effort just to get this question answerable, seeing how you didn't even include the file involved with the problem, making it almost impossible to answer in the first place. You could always look for a site that allows you to request debugging help! I'm sure there are plenty out there

Comment: @VinceEmigh i edited it now i include the content of my text file

Comment: @rpy i edited now my question :)

Comment: Try `info[0].equals("VOTED")`... matches will match both Voted and Not Voted

Comment: You also failed to include your full code. What are the President and Vice_President methods?

Comment: @cricket_007 i edit it now and i include the President method which is still very similar to Vice_President method. and i tried doing what you suggested and but then it is still the same